# Recursive Tree Mapping

Tags: c#, parsing, data-structures, recursion, binary-tree

I've been working a lot with tree implementations lately and how we represent and understand trees. My focus has been on turning mathematical expressions into binary trees, I set the problem of representing a tree in a linear form say a string or an array, while still retaining important information about the tree and its sub trees.

As such I have developed a really simple encoding for binary expression trees does just this. However I am having some issues with implementing it effectively in a recursive manor, it seems to be the one failing aspect behind the concept.

The encoding is simple if the node resides as a left child it is given a map of 1 if it resides as a right child it is given a 0. This simple encoding allows me to encode entire balanced and unbalanced trees like this:

```
           ##                      ##
          /  \                    /  \
         1    0         OR       1    0
        / \  / \                     / \
       11 10 01 00                  01  00
```

Etc to trees of depth N

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to create a recursive function that would create the prefix string representing a mapping of this sort (for example ## 1 11 10 0 01 00).

I was told this would be difficult/impossible due to having to keep track of alternating between 1 and 0 while retaining and concatenating to the value of the parent.

I wondered if anyone had any insight or ideas into how to do this with C# ??

Comment: There seems to be a lot of redundancy in your scheme. In particular, each node encodes the path to it form the root. With this kind of scheme, listing the encodings of the leaf nodes will suffice to fully represent the tree. Dunno if this helps, just an observation.

Comment: I need to retain that route so that I can effectively determine sub expressions and how they interact as whole.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand you problem but here is something that might help.  One solution might be implementing graph traversal routine on a Graph (remember a Tree is a specialized Graph), where the visit occurs the first time you encounter a node/vertex. I apologize for posting Java code when you asked for C# but I happen know Java...

```
public void depthFirstSearch(Graph graph, Vertex start){
    Set<Vertex> visited = new HashSet<Vertex>(); // could use vertex.isVisited()...
    Deque<Vertex> stack = new ArrayDeque<Vertex>(); // stack implies depth first

    // first visit the root element, then add it to the stack so
    // we will visit it's children in a depth first order
    visit(start);
    visited.add(start);
    stack.push(start);   

    while(stack.isEmpty() == false){
        List<Edge> edges = graph.getEdges(stack.peekFirst());
        Vertex nextUnvisited = null;
        for(Edge edge : edges){
            if(visited.contains(edge.getEndVertex)) == false){
               nextUnvisited = edge.getEndVertex();
               break; // break for loop
            }
        }
        if(nextUnvisited == null){
            // check the next item in the stack
            Vertex popped = stack.pop();
        } else {
            // visit adjacent unvisited vertex
            visit(nextUnvisited);
            visited.add(nextUnvisited);
            stack.push(nextUnvisited); // visit it's "children"
        }
    }
}

public void visit(Vertex vertex){
    // your own visit logic (string append, etc)
}
```

You can easily modify this to be a breadth first search by using the Deque as a queue instead of stack as follows:

```
stack.pop()  >>>>  queue.removeFirst()
stack.push() >>>>  queue.addLast()
```

Note that for this purpose the Graph and Edge classes support the following operations :

```
public interface Graph {
    ...
    // get edges originating from Vertex v
    public List<Edge> getEdges(Vertex v);
    ...
}

public interface Edge {
    ...
    // get the vertex at the start of the edge
    // not used here but kind of implied by the getEndVertex()...
    public Vertex getStartVertex();
    // get the vertex at the end of the edge
    public Vertex getEndVertex();
    ...
}
```

Hopefully that gives you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Well i don't know if i completely get your question but it seems you want a preorder traversal of the tree. I don't know c#'s syntax but the pseudocode i think will be as follows:

```
preorder_traversal(node)
    if(node != NULL)
        print(node)
        preorder_traversal(left_sub_child)
        preorder_traversal(right_sub_child)
    else
        return
```

Answer (score 1):

Building a tree recursively is a difficult challenge even for a seasoned programmer. I realize I'm a bit late to the party on this question considering it was originally posted in March of 2011. Better late than never?

One important factor in creating a tree is just making sure your dataset is formatted correctly. You simply need a way to associate a parent to a child. Once the association is clearly defined, then you can begin to code the solution. I chose to use a simple format like this:

```
ParentId ChildId
1        2
1        3
2        4
3        5
```

Etc.

Once that relationship is established, I developed a recursive method to iterate through the dataset to build the tree.

First I identify all the parent nodes and store them in a collection giving them each a unique identifier using a combination of the parent ID and child ID:

```
 private void IdentifyParentNodes()
{
    SortedList<string, MyTreeNode> newParentNodes = new SortedList<string,MyTreeNode>();
    Dictionary<string, string> parents = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (MyTreeNode oParent in MyTreeDataSource.Values)
    {
        if (!parents.ContainsValue(oParent.ParentId))
        {
            parents.Add(oParent.ParentId + "." + oParent.ChildId, oParent.ParentId);

            newParentNodes.Add(oParent.ParentId + "." + oParent.ChildId, oParent);
        }
    }

    this._parentNodes = newParentNodes;
}
```

Then the root calling method would loop through the parents and call the recursive method to build the tree:

```
// Build the rest of the tree
foreach (MyTreeNode node in ParentNodes.Values)
{
    RecursivelyBuildTree(node);
}
```

Recursive method:

```
private void RecursivelyBuildTree(MyTreeNode node)
{
    int nodePosition = 0;

    _renderedTree.Append(FormatNode(MyTreeNodeType.Parent, node, 0));
    _renderedTree.Append(NodeContainer("open", node.ParentId));

    foreach (MyTreeNode child in GetChildren(node.ParentId).Values)
    {
        nodePosition++;
        if (IsParent(child.ChildId))
        {
            RecursivelyBuildTree(child);
        }
        else
        {
            _renderedTree.Append(FormatNode(MyTreeNodeType.Leaf, child, nodePosition));
        }
    }
    _renderedTree.Append(NodeContainer("close", node.ParentId));
}
```

Method used to get children of a parent:

```
private SortedList<string, MyTreeNode> GetChildren(string parentId)
{
    SortedList<string, MyTreeNode> childNodes = new SortedList<string, MyTreeNode>();
    foreach (MyTreeNode node in this.MyTreeDataSource.Values)
    {
        if (node.ParentId == parentId)
        {
            childNodes.Add(node.ParentId + node.ChildId, node);
        }
    }
    return childNodes;
}
```

Not that complex or elegant, but it got the job done. This was written in 2007 time frame, so it's old code, but it still works. :-) Hope this helps.